# How to make a String include the ':' in between numbers only avoid the ':' before or after any character java?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I want to make a String highlighted with the SpannableString java

I have the following string

```
    textString = "2021-01-26 19:23:18 Lat: 26.369919 Long: 83.46433";
```

From this, I am able to highlight the String using regex with decimal numbers from this

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
```

like this

textString = "**2021**-**01**-**26** **19**:**23**:**18** Lat: **26.369919** Long: **83.46433**";

But now I want to make s String including the ':' in between numbers also and want to avoid the ':' before or after any nonnumeric character

I want to produce output like this

textString = "**2021**-**01**-**26** **19:23:18** Lat: **26.369919** Long: **83.46433**";

Comment: Isn't the output you want to produce the same as the string you have? I don't see any difference.

Comment: 19:23:18   look at this String. I want to include ':' between numbers my code avoiding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include `:` in your character class inside the optional non-capture group and make non-capture group match 0 or more times:

```sh
\\d+(?:[:.]\\d+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFYkBr/1)

Replacement would be:

```
"<b>$0</b>"
```

Note that this will match a number with multiple dots like `83.46433.135`.

If you want to eliminate that then use:

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+|(?::\\d+)+)?
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/RFYkBr/2)

Comment: This is really more of an Android question than pure regex.  The OP wants to display bold face text in its Android app, and wants to use spannable string or some alternative to that.

Comment: Yes that is understood but which part of my answer is not compatible with Java/Android code?

Comment: I have seen that. You are just calling `.replaceAll` with a regex to get numbers wrapped in `<b>` and `</b>` and that is exactly what I had showed in my demo links as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Html#fromHtml` here for a fairly straightforward approach:

```java
String textString = "2021-01-26 19:23:18 Lat: 26.369919 Long: 83.46433";
textString = textString.replaceAll("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})", "<b>$1</b>-<b>$2</b>-<b>$3</b> <b>$4</b>");
textString = textString.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?!\\S)", "<b>$1</b>");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textString));
```

If you were to log the value of `textString` after the regex replacement, you would see this value:

```
<b>2021</b>-<b>01</b>-<b>26</b> <b>19:23:18</b> Lat: <b>26.369919</b> Long: <b>83.46433</b>
```

Comment: As per OP's desired output `-`s are not part of highlighted text.

Comment: @anubhava Good eye...you read more closely than I did.  I had to edit the question to see where the OP actually wants boldface.  My answer just got a whole lot uglier, but I think is correct now.

Comment: Thanks, but we can get same output using [much simpler regex](https://regex101.com/r/RFYkBr/1) as I have in my answer.